# SQL add table subset for each distinct value in another table

Tags: sql, join, hana-studio

I want to add a subset of a table `(t2)` to another table `(t1)` for each `customer_id` once.

`t1` represents ordered materials. `t2` represents a static table representing high-seller materials.

The goal is to create a table with material lists for each customer. `(t2)` does not include any `customer_id` reference but a `region_id` key.

Basically what I need is "add this subset material list to your existing material list for `each customer` based on his region"

I can't figure out how to `join/union` those tables without a `customer_id`, as I will get duplicated entries.

`t1` looks like this:

| Customer_id | region_id | material_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 155 | NAM | AA-123-526 |
| 155 | NAM | AA-425-123 |
| 157 | NAM | AA-123-623 |
| 157 | NAM | AA-612-244 |
| 158 | SOA | AA-123-456 |
| 158 | SOA | AA-655-876 |

`t2` looks like this:

| region_id | material_id |
| --- | --- |
| NAM | BB-724-623 |
| NAM | BB-421-125 |
| DACH | BB-123-622 |
| DACH | BB-421-231 |
| SOA | BB-123-551 |
| SOA | BB-421-125 |

desired output:

| Customer_id | region_id | material_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 155 | NAM | AA-123-526 |
| 155 | NAM | AA-425-123 |
| 155 | NAM | BB-724-623 |
| 155 | NAM | BB-421-125 |
| 157 | NAM | AA-123-623 |
| 157 | NAM | AA-612-244 |
| 157 | NAM | BB-724-623 |
| 157 | NAM | BB-421-125 |
| 158 | SOA | AA-123-456 |
| 158 | SOA | AA-655-876 |
| 158 | SOA | BB-123-551 |
| 158 | SOA | BB-421-125 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Sample data**

```
SELECT * FROM t1
SELECT * FROM t2
```

[image]

**Solution**

```
SELECT  t1.Customer_id, t1.region_id, t1.material_id FROM t1
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT t1.Customer_id, t2.region_id, t2.material_id
FROM t2 INNER JOIN t1 ON t2.region_id = t1.region_id
ORDER BY t1.Customer_id
```

[image]

Comment: thanks! I checked it with this logic and it works as intended.